# why i am getting AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_trace'

Tags: python, pdb

```
import pdb 
print("program started") 
c=100 
d=200 
pdb.set_trace() 
def fun(a,b): 
    print a,b 
    return a+b 
fun(c,d) 
for i in [1,2,3,4,5]: 
    print 10/i 
    print ("other statements in program") 
print ("program ended")
```

Comment: Can you indent your code properly and format it as code as well?

Comment: Do you have your own module called pdb?

Comment: pdb - A python debugger @Jens

Comment: @vkgade but if i have a module with same Name in actual working Directory, this will be used, not the python pdb mdule!

Comment: Oh, okay, seems to be the here then. @Jens

Answer (score 9):

The python module `pdb` has a `set_trace()` function. Since your program is not finding it, it is importing something else. Almost certainly, you named your program (or another program in the same directory) `pdb.py`.

Comment: For me it was `tokenize.py`

Answer (score 8):

been here couple of times, either your file is `pdb.py` or `code.py` or some reserved file name python recognizes.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "reserved file name that python recognizes" -- certainly nothing that would lead to this behavior. It must be `pdb.py` (as I answered when the question was asked ;-) ).

Comment: My python script was named `code.py`. Changing the filename solved the issue for me.

Comment: I guess the lesson learned is that one should not use the filename `<name>.py` if `<name>` is a module appearing in Python's standard library.

Answer (score -1):

it works fine for me

`

```
[root@ebs-49393 tmp]# cat test.py 
import json,pdb
buf = open('./a.txt').read()
j = json.loads(buf)
pdb.set_trace()
print j
[root@ebs-49393 tmp]# python test.py 
> /tmp/test.py(5)<module>()
-> print j
(Pdb) list
  1     import json,pdb
  2     buf = open('./a.txt').read()
  3     j = json.loads(buf)
  4     pdb.set_trace()
  5  -> print j
[EOF]
```

`

also in interactive mode, you can use help(pdb) to see if it is using the right module.

Answer (score -1):

Your python file name should not be **pdb.py**. I have saved it initially like this and I got the same error, changing the file name to **pdb1.py** worked well.

Answer (score -1):

Never use the libraries that you import into the your program as a filename for any of the files in that directories. The import function first checks the modules you have installed in the directory that you are working in and then check it in the python environment you have setup.

Answer (score -1):

Its because of the name of your python file being same as the file you are trying to import, in this case your filename being **pdb.py** and you are trying to **import pdb**. This could result in a circular import. Rename the file and it will work.